# Not able to send data packets over UDP

Tags: c, sockets, udp

This is the code I used for Data transfer over UDP network

```
// server program for udp connection 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strings.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define PORT xxxx 
#define MAXLINE 1000 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{    
    char buffer[100]; 
    char *message = "Hello Client"; 
    int listenfd, len; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // Create a UDP Socket 
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);         
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.xx.xx"); //htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;  

    // bind server address to socket descriptor 
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    //receive the datagram

    while(1){

    len = sizeof(cliaddr); 
    int n = recvfrom(listenfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
            0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len); //receive message from server 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    puts(buffer);

    // send the response 
    sendto(listenfd, message, strlen(message), 0, 
          (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

     } 
}
```

this is my code which runs perfectly with `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions over there.
but when I try to execute only `sendto` function just to only send data over UDP network. It stops working

```
while(1){

    len = sizeof(cliaddr); 
    /*int n = recvfrom(listenfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
            0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len); //receive message from server 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    puts(buffer);*/

    // send the response 
    sendto(listenfd, message, strlen(message), 0, 
          (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

     }
```

after doing this my network stop sending data to client device.

What should I do to overcome this issue?

anyone please help me!

Comment: If you don't call `recvfrom` then `clientaddr` is not filled in.

Comment: Furthermore you should always check return values of `sendto`/`recvfrom`. They return -1 on error, and in that case you might want to perform a specific behavior.

Comment: Okay, I checked for return value of `sendto` function, it returns a positive number @RobertoCaboni. What should I do for a successful send?

Comment: A positive number is a successful send.

Comment: @kaylum, Got your point, can you please suggest me something to solve this problem. I tried by using the same servaddr instead of cliaddr in `sendto` function

Comment: No I can't suggest anything because I really don't know what you are trying to do by removing the `recvfrom`. You didn't explain why you would want to do that. You need to tell us where you think you can get the client address from if not from a `recvfrom`. Normally a server receives a request and sends back to the client. So if the server is not responding to a received request how does it know what client to send to?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, yes but I am not getting any data to my device after commenting reception part. I am using UDP sender/Receiver android application in receive only mode

Comment: @kaylum, what I want to do is, just to send data over client socket (Client IP + Port). I don't want to initiate my communication after receiving any data from client machine. I just want to broadcast my data.

Comment: Ok, then how does the server know which client to send to? That is something only you can answer. Or perhaps you want to send multicast packets. If so, that is a big topic which can't be covered in a Q&A forum like this. You would need to research that and come back to ask a  more specific question once you have gotten a bit further.

Comment: @kaylum , I am providing IP address and port address of the client machine. is it possible to broadcast using this information about client?

Comment: Broadcast is not the right term in that case as that is still a unicast. If you have the ip address and port then you just need to directly fill in the `clientaddr` with that info. Then it should work. That's what I was trying to ask you when I said "You need to tell us where you think you can get the client address from".

Comment: Your program was able to contact your android peer because was the first to send data (your application is a server and retrieves addresses from incoming data!) If you stop receiving, you need to populate manually `struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;`

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem @kaylum

Comment: You are using neither [tag:serversocket] nor [tag:udpclient]. Don't tag indiscrminately.